# How to transfer multiply commits from one branch to another using git?

Tags: git, git-workflow

There are two branches:
- production branch which contains product accepted by customer
- develop branch where developers perform their creepy experiments
Once upon a time young developer decided to branch his super feature from productive branch.
So the qustions:
**1).** How can I transfer production branch to develop without merging all acenstors of feature from prod branch. The picture explains better:

[image]

The first question is for practice, another questions for curiosity:
**2).** Same as 1) + I need to keep feature branch from production also
**3).** Like 1), but I want transfer consistent set of commits "F" and don't want transfer "E" commits
**4).** I want transfer E and F excluding 2 commits, 1 commit from set "E" and 1 commit from set "F".
**5).**  Can I automatically resolve conflicts in favor of one of branches?

I found `git cherry-pick` command, but seems it is not the best way for whole branch. Should i study `git rebase` or something else? Which way is the best for my problem?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Investigate `git rebase -i` to answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick production..feature
```

does exactly what you want for your first question, it cherry-picks every commit in `feature` that isn't also in `production`'s history.  For the rest of your questions, various other ways of specifying commit ranges as found in the [gitrevisions manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) will work, and after you're familiar with those, and it starts to seem a bit tedious working out how to specify a list or you start wanting to make amendments as you go, you'll be ready to appreciate `rebase -i`.

One small detail: `cherry-pick` and `rebase` make new commits.